# WooCommerce REST API v2 - Show Protected Meta Data

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am integrating a WooCommerce website into an application I've built.

I am attempting to retrieve custom fields for products (meta data) using the API.

The below is an excerpt from the docs regarding changes from v1 to v2

> v1 does not include order item meta, v2 includes full order item meta (**with an optional filter parameter to include protected order item meta**)
>
> https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v2.html#version

I cannot seem to find anywhere what this actual filter is. The filter below is what's used to get meta data initially

```
filter[meta]=true
```

But through my searching, I cannot find the additional filter to return protected meta data for products. Note I am not trying to update protected meta, but just view protected meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for now. I did not find a filter for protected fields in the API call however I added the following code to my functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'is_protected_meta', function ( $protected, $key, $type ) {
    if ( $key === '_my_protected_meta_field' ) {
        // Expose the `_my_protected_meta_field` meta value publicly
        return false;
    }
    return $protected;
}, 10, 3 );
```

The meta data for `_my_protected_meta_field` now shows in the API call with `filter[meta]=true`